# vncserver dies immediately upon start

Tags: centos, vnc

I'm trying to configure VNC server for remote logins on a fresh install of CentOS 7, but I just can't seem to get it working right.

I've followed the install steps [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/vnc-server-installation-on-centos-7) including the firewall-cmd steps, but when I run systemctl status vncserver@:1.service, I see:

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:1.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since <~4 seconds after start time>
Main PID: 1462 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

<start time> localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Remote desktop service (VNC)...
<start time+3> localhost.localdomaind systemd[1]: Started Remote desktop service (VNC).
```

When I instead try to run vncserver manually (as su - remote-user), the log output (in /home/remote-user/.vnc/localhost.localdomain:1.log) is:

```
  vncext: VNC extension running!
  vncext: Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5901
  vncext: created VNC server for screen 0
Killing Xvnc process ID 17085
```

Other thing that may be causing or contributing to the issue:

In /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:1.service, the line:

```
PIDFile=/home/remote-user/.vnc/%H%i.pid
```

Doesn't appear to generate any .pid files. /home/remote-user/.vnc contains no files ending in .pid; this may be because the vnc process doesn't live long enough to create them, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 8):

Just check your */home/username/.vnc/xstartup* file and remove the last line

This is how it looked in my case:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
vncserver -kill $DISPLAY
```

*vncserver -kill $DISPLAY* is definetely not something we want in xstartup, just remove it

Comment: While this might have solved your problem, please: Do not recommend to blindly erase the last line of the startup file. Be more specific of what should be searched.

Comment: I was quite specific, do you usually read only the first line of the message or the whole post?

Comment: Commenting on a months-old post to thank @ilya.s for a sufficiently specific answer that pointed me in exactly the right direction. The last line of `~/.vnc/xstartup` will always be `vncserver -kill $DISPLAY` for a fresh install, and besides, you provide the full contents of your file, and specifically mention that `vncserver -kill $DISPLAY` is the offending line.

Comment: This did prevent my vnc session from being terminated, but instead of showing the remote desktop, I got a black screen. There is something wrong with the display in my case.

Comment: @AaronSwan same, did you find how to solve the issue?

Comment: This doesn't explain why this line ended up in xstartup in the first place if it is "definitely not something we want in xstartup".

Comment: ‘vncserver’ does not have much information in the log file.  ```yum groupinstall "Server with GUI" -y``` solved the problem